# Magento - product attributes - recommended maximum?

Tags: magento

I'm looking to add a significant number (about 200) product attributes to a Magento installation.  Most of them will be binary.

I see that each attribute adds a column to the flat product table.  Should I expect to see a performance hit because of the addition of these attributes?  What's the best practice for number of attributes?

---

Edit:  We're using Magento 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you should be aware of is max Mysql row size. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html) article for explanation. Here's one excerpt from it to understand What I'm talking about:

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.
>
> The maximum row size constrains the number (and possibly size) of columns because the total length of all columns cannot exceed this size. For example, utf8 characters require up to three bytes per character, so for a CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 column, the server must allocate 255 × 3 = 765 bytes per value. Consequently, a table cannot contain more than 65,535 / 765 = 85 such columns.

So if the total size of your 200 attribute exceeds this value (65,535 bytes), you just won't be able to store all your attributes in Flat table. In that case you should shorten the amount of attributes you have, or simply **do not place ALL your attributes to Flat table**. You need there only attributes that should be available on Product Listing pages. I don't thing that you're going to show all 200 there...

Comment: Good stuff.  Question is, even within the MYSQL limits, will Magento performance degrade given, e.g. 250 columns in the flat table?

Comment: well of course the `select` execution time from a larger table will be greater than from the smaller table. I can't tell you how much slower it will be, but I think you won't notice the difference, since it's only one small request among many others during the Magento page load flow. The only way you can feel the performance decrease is if the table will become so large, it no longer fits in memory. Than disk operations will take place, and those are much slower.