# Magento Reindexing doesn't work

Tags: magento, reindex

I recently created around 700 attributes through script, all attributes look fine at backend.
But when I reindex, I get following error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.additional_information_s' in 'field
>   list'' in  /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Note: this attribtue exist in Database (eav_attribtue) table.

I would highly appreciate suggestion.

Comment: which reindex exactly ? If product flat, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893772/magento-product-attributes-recommended-maximum

Comment: Reindex got failed on catalog_fulltextsearch

Comment: For, I didn't set backend model for the attribute so I was getting such reindex fail error. When I corrected this, reindex works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

The following will reindex each index.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

You can also use the Magento collection model to load each index rather than hard coding the id in the for loop.

```
/* @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection */
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */
    $index->reindexAll();
}
```

But if you want to reindex just the price the id is 2

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
$process->reindexAll();
```

You could also call the function getProcessByCode as follows:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```